# Is there anyway to edit the actual theme of the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, eclipse-cdt

I'm not talking about the themes we can easily import and edit the textpad and code coloring with.

What I'm wondering is just like the firefox themes where the frame of the window and buttons can change colors. Is there a theme option for the actual editor not the text pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for 

http://ikool.wordpress.com/2008/07/06/eclipse-skins-to-make-your-eclipse-ide-spicy/ 

http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/presentation_shelf/presentation_shelf.php
although it doesn't change everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse Juno (4.2), there is a plugin for this: https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes (of course, the .css files in the application can also be edited manually)